# error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol _CLSID_CMP3DecMediaObject

Tags: windows, mp3, codec, dmo

I want to use mp3 decoder to decode mp3 file. But I get the following link error:
`error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol _CLSID_CMP3DecMediaObject`

Which lib should I link with?

Comment: add `wmcodecdspuuid.lib`

Comment: Greate,how do you know this?I've searched everywhere.

Comment: i first listen about `CMP3DecMediaObject` at all. but found this is very simply. go to lib folder (say in modern sdk/ddk) this is `\Windows Kits\10\Lib\<version>\um\x86\` ans search (case sensitive) this symbol in all  files.